# How to make a unversal timeoutable function wrapper in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timeout

I have a bunch of functions with blocking calls which could hang in case of network connectivity loss or other issues. I want to make an universal wrapper allowing to run passed function with specified timout and arguments.

A function prototypes:

```
public static double Func1(string ip, string username, string password);
public static int Func2(string ip, string username, string password, string dir);
```

My wrapper:

```
    public static T? ExecuteAsync<T>(Func<object[], T> func, int timeout /* sec */, params object[] args) where T : struct
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => func(args));
        if (task.Wait(timeout * 1000))
            return task.Result;
        return null;
    }
```

Expected usage:

```
var res1 = ExecuteAsync<double>(Func1, 30, "1.1.1.1", "user", "looser");
var res2 = ExecuteAsync<int>(Func2, 20, "1.1.1.1", "user", "looser", "home");
```

Compiler errors here (on line with call to `ExecuteAsync`):

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Func'

I found a compilable code

```
var res = ExecuteAsync((args) => Func1(args[0].ToString(), args[1].ToString(), args[2].ToString()), 50, "ip", "user", "pass");
```

It is too heavy and unreadable. Is it possible to simplify it? How to fix original error? Maybe there is an another way to reach the goal?
I see examples with `Action`, but my functions are returning a value and they have different argument list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is the signature of `Func1` has three string args whereas your `ExecuteAsync` method's first arg expects a "method" with object array as the argument
i.e. `object[]` != `string, string, string`

```
public static double Func1(string ip, string username, string password);
Func<object[], T>
```

The simplest solution you can have is to standardize the signature of all the "blocking functions". In that case your situation would look like below code. You lose type-safety in this. This approach is used by the `Thread` class

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var res1 = ExecuteAsync<double>(Func1, 30, "1.1.1.1", "user", "looser");
}

public static double Func1(object[] args) {
    string ip = (string)args[0], username = (string)args[1], password = (string)args[2];
    // do some work 
    return 0.0;
}

public static T? ExecuteAsync<T>(Func<object[], T> func, int timeout /* sec */, params object[] args) where T : struct {
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => func(args));
    if (task.Wait(timeout * 1000))
        return task.Result;
    return null;
}
```

If you don't want to lose type safety, you can create multiple overloads of the `ExecuteAsync` method - similar to how .NET framework creates multiple overloads for `Func`. In that case, you `ExecuteAsync` method will look like below. You can create other overloads for 1, 2, 4, 5 arg methods just like how `Func` is implemented

```
public static TRes? ExecuteAsync<T1, T2, T3, TRes>(Func<T1, T2, T3, TRes> func, int timeout /* sec */, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3) where TRes : struct {
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => func(arg1, arg2, arg3));
    if (task.Wait(timeout * 1000))
        return task.Result;
    return null;
}
```